# framework7 Login redirect issue?

Tags: jquery, authentication, html-framework-7

If the user has already logged in then it should redirect to profile page. I have tried many thing but didnt succeed. The following is my code. Please help me with this.

```
myApp.onPageInit('account', function (page) {
var userLoggedIn=window.localStorage.getItem(“id”);
if (userLoggedIn!=null) {
mainView.router.loadPage({url:'updateprofile.html', ignoreCache:true, reload:true });
}
})
```

I also tried this,

```
mainView.router.loadPage('updateprofile.html');
```

But no effect